# Flutter Access denied finding property "camera.hal1.packagelist" avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0"

Tags: android, flutter, android-camera

im building flutter application and using PlatformView to show camera preview android plugin for face verification but the camera preview not rendering.
Log error :

```
- W/Thread-5: type=1400 audit(0.0:593012): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14074 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c75,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
- E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.hal1.packagelist"
```

Permission :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

All permission granted, how to fix this? if i try run sample application using native android its work.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

in my case. I changed the app's camera permission on my phone from deny to allow

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).